# Oracle row level security by column value, not by user id

Tags: sql, oracle, security

I'm learning Oracle and I'm trying to add Row Level Security to a demo
table. I can run successfully this first example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp_pred
    (schema_v IN VARCHAR2, tbl_v IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN
       RETURN 'upper(ename) = SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''CURRENT_USER'') 
        OR upper(manager) = SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''CURRENT_USER'')';
    END;

BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY(
        object_schema   => 'hector',
        object_name     => 'emp',
        policy_name     => 'emp_vpd1',
        function_schema => 'vpdadmin',
        policy_function => 'get_emp_pred',
        statement_types => 'select'
    );
END;
```

In this example every user can see the rows where column 'ename' or column 'manager'
value matches his own user name. Now my problem is when I try to filter
not comparing by a user in a column but for some arbitrary column value like country or
salary. For example I want to show rows to Bob where salary > 1000, to Anne
where salary < 1000 and show all the rows to other users.

I tried this function and other variants without result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp_pred
(schema_v IN VARCHAR2, tbl_v IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    l_predicate VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN 
        IF 'BOB' = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') THEN
            l_predicate := 'salary > 1000';
        ELSIF 'ANNE' = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') THEN
            l_predicate := 'salary < 1000'; 
        ELSE 
            l_predicate := '1=1';
        END IF;
        RETURN l_predicate;
     END;
```

I suppose you can not evaluate this conditions at runtime, but if I write one
policy for every user and predicate it doesn't work neither. For example this
function with its policy for Bob, other for Anne, etc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp_pred_bob
    (schema_v IN VARCHAR2, tbl_v IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN 
        RETURN '''BOB'' = SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''CURRENT_USER'') AND salary > 1000';
    END;
```

If I have only the Bob policy it works for Bob and return 0 rows for other users,
but when I add a second policy for Anne I get 0 rows for everybody, maybe because
policyBob && policyAnne returns always false.

I want to know if this kind of filtering is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `get_emp_pred` function isn't doing what you expect because it is a (default) definer's rights function. That means that within the function, `current_user` is the owner, VPDADMIN, not the user performing the query.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086) `current_user` gives:

> The name of the database user whose privileges are currently active. This may change during the duration of a database session ... to reflect the owner of any active definer's rights object. When no definer's rights object is active, `CURRENT_USER` returns the same value as `SESSION_USER`.

So if you change `current_user` to `session_user` in the second function then it should do what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp_pred
(schema_v IN VARCHAR2, tbl_v IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    l_predicate VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN 
        IF 'BOB' = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') THEN
            l_predicate := 'salary > 1000';
        ELSIF 'ANNE' = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') THEN
            l_predicate := 'salary < 1000'; 
        ELSE 
            l_predicate := '1=1';
        END IF;
        RETURN l_predicate;
     END;
```

Your first function doesn't suffer from that because  the user is evaluated in the predicate as part of the query, not within the function.

---

> when I add a second policy for Anne I get 0 rows for everybody, maybe because policyBob && policyAnne returns always false.

Yes, both policies are applied, and you end up with mutually exclusive predicates applied to the query, so now rows can match.

---

You could make this work with a single policy and function that returns a predicate that ORs together all the options; something like:

```
RETURN q'[(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') = 'BOB' AND salary > 1000)
       OR (SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') = 'ANNE' AND salary < 1000)
       OR (SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') NOT IN ('BOB', 'ANNE'))'];
```

But using PL/SQL logic to return different predicates is simpler - as long as it doesn't impact performance. It's possible a static policy with a single fixed complex predicate could perform better.